# How do I make my list item display inline?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Whenever I use `display: inline` in the CSS for the list item, it doesn't do anything.

[image: Image of the problem]

I would like for the list items to display inline.

**CSS**

```
.clipit-routes {
    flex: 2;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-links {
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-link {
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="clipit-routes">
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Github</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you put a working snippet up which shows the problem (i.e. including the basic HTML). Did you mean to overwrite the display: flex with display: inline?

Comment: Having the display flex, and not having it doesn't change anything. The CSS Snippet is in the post already, I will add a html snippet aswell.

Comment: Having ul as display inline doesn't affect the li elements. Are you trying to get the li elements inline?

Comment: Yep! I'm trying to get the li elements to display inline

Comment: I've added a ".nav-link li" to the css, and added a display inline for it. Still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of small changes needed: nav-link should be nav-links in the final class setting and it's the li elements, not the ul element, that you want to get inline.

```css
.clipit-routes {
  flex: 2;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-links {
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links li {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="clipit-routes">
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Upload</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Github</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply li to the correct elements.  In this case it would be the < li>'s

```css
li{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="clipit-routes">
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Github</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```